# What does the 'EA' in EAGLContext stand for?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

What does '**EA**' in EAGLContext stand for? Is it also the same for the 'EA' in CAEAGLLayer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EAGL (Embedded Apple Graphics Library) is the implementation by Apple of the EGL API.

EA = **Embedded Apple**. Yes it is also the **same** for CAEAGLLayer.

Answer (score 3):

EA = Embedded Apple. It comes from AGL, the Apple Graphics Library and EA(GL) is the embedded version of it.

Answer (score 1):

EAGL stands for **Embedded Apple** Graphics Library